# Sum rows two by two

Tags: r, sum

I would like to obtain the sum the rows of a dataframe two by two. That´s my input:

```
input <- 'name sample1 sample2 sample3
          pr_001A  300  200    300
          pr_001B  233  211   333
          pr_002A  244  214  214  
          pr_002B  234  233  213'
input <- read.table(text=input, header=T)
```

To obtain this output:

```
output <- 'name sample1 sample2 sample3
              pr_001  533  411    633
              pr_002  478  447  427'  
output <- read.table(text=output, header=T)
```

Thus, for `pr_001` in `sample1` the result is `300 + 233 = 533`, and the same logic must be follow for all samples and names. Some idea to deal with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option with *data.table*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(name = sub(".$", "", name))]
#      name sample1 sample2 sample3
# 1: pr_001     533     411     633
# 2: pr_002     478     447     427
```

Or with the `aggregate()` formula method (@rawr has already shown the data.frame method in the comments)

```
aggregate(. ~ cbind(name = sub(".$", "", input$name)), input[-1], sum)
#     name sample1 sample2 sample3
# 1 pr_001     533     411     633
# 2 pr_002     478     447     427
```

And another with *dplyr*

```
library(dplyr)
summarise_each(group_by(input, name = sub(".$", "", name)), funs(sum))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#
#     name sample1 sample2 sample3
#    (chr)   (int)   (int)   (int)
# 1 pr_001     533     411     633
# 2 pr_002     478     447     427
```

Comment: `dplyr` seems like a very nice successor of `plyr`. I'll look into it more closely (if only it didn't crash some of my codes that work fine with `plyr`)

Answer (score 0):

Option with `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
input <- 'name sample1 sample2 sample3
          pr_001A  300  200    300
          pr_001B  233  211   333
          pr_002A  244  214  214  
          pr_002B  234  233  213'
input <- read.table(text=input, header=T)

input$aux_name = gsub("[A-Z]$","",input$name)
result = ddply(input, .(aux_name),summarize, sum(sample1), sum(sample2),sum(sample3))
View(result)

    aux_name    ..1 ..2 ..3
1   pr_001  533 411 633
2   pr_002  478 447 427
```